# Do 2-forms and higher live in the cotangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Trying to self-study differential forms from a roughly high school maths level. I've got the concept (hopefully) that each point of a manifold is home to vectors (the tangent space) and 1-forms (the cotangent space) and if you have a metric you can flip between them. But how about higher forms such as 2-forms, 3-forms etc? Do they houseshare with 1-forms in the same cotangent space or do they have their own space?

Comment: A cotangent eats a vector field and spits out a scalar function. 2-forms eat _two_ vector fields and spit out a scalar function. That doesn't sound exactly like a covector to me. But it's close.

Comment: I'm nervous of saying anything here because I've just clocked your massive reputation, but shouldn't that be "a covector eats a vector field"? And are you saying all forms live in the same cotangent space?

Comment: Yes, it should be "covector" (and perhaps a covector field?). And don't mind the reputation. I've been here a while and answered a lot of simple calculus and algebra questions. That doesn't mean I automatically know what I'm talking about when discussing differential geometry. I have some experience in the field, but I'm no authority.

Comment: So, without getting too technical, is it correct that at a point all differential forms live in the same cotangent space? I hope so as I can sort of get my head around that idea.

Answer (score 1):

The 1-forms are covectors. They eat vectors and spit out scalars. However, a 2-form is not a covector, as feeding it a vector gives you a 1-form, not a scalar. So they aren't the same kind of animal, and as such, they don't live in the same space. At least not in such a simple manner.

You *can* make a space that contains all of them, though. It's called the *exterior algebra* on the vector space of covectors. Put simply, it's the direct sum of all the spaces of $n$-forms for different $n$ (including $n=0$, the scalar functions). Kind of like how a polynomial ring over, say, $\Bbb R$ is a direct sum of different copies of $\Bbb R$ (at least when only considering the structure as an $\Bbb R$-vector space).

In this exterior algebra, you have a product called the *wedge product* which, at least in notation, looks a lot like polynomial multiplication. And when adding, like with polynomials, different degree terms do not really interact with one another.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to digest that. Referring to your first paragraph, do for example, 2-forms have their own space, and what would that be called? Similarly, for 3-forms, etc.

Comment: @Peter4075 "The space of 2-forms" is a good candidate. According to Wikipedia, "2nd exterior power of the space of covectors" is an option.